# Correct usage of wslite plugin for grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I  use wslite plugin in my grails app and the way I currently have it setup is that I have the wslite configuration in a grails service class. I read in the grails documentation that grails service classes are there to provide transactional behavior. My question is: Should I be writing the code for wslite plugin in a grails service or can I also just write it in a groovy class? I need some justification for either approaches. How are people using it out there?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either. Grails services are transactional and singelton by default. The transactional nature can be disabled by setting

```
static transactional = false
```

no further code changes necesary.

As the service is scoped as a singleton you can add performance by getting the build-up code done (like getting references to your libs, stub generation, or whatever) during initialisation / instantiation.